# How do I know when to use nCr button and when to use nPr button on my calculator in which situation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I know when to use nCr button and when to use nPr button  on my calculator?

nCr= combinations I believe 
NPR= permutations

Is there a general rule I can use to figure out which one to use and when according to the given question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In permutations, order counts.
So, if I wanted to know the number of ways to *arrange* a set of four unique books out of a total supply of 20 books, I'd use $20$ `nPr` $4$.  (Order counts in arranging books.)

In combinations, order doesn't count.
So, if I wanted to know the number of ways to make a team of $4$ people out of a total group of $20$ people, I'd use $20$ `nCr` $4$.  This is because order doesn't matter in choosing a team.

Comment: @ anorton how do you know that order  does or doesn't matter? Ie: how many ways can I get a license plate with different plate combinations. Here the order will matter right?

Comment: Yes.  Because the license tag `ABC123` is much different to the police officer pulling me over than the tag `BCA321`.  The best way to tell if order matters is to imagine the situation in your head the best way you can.

Comment: Oops... forgot to @-notify you, @MethodManX (I don't know if you're notified of comments on answers to your questions)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to calculate ${}_nC_r=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, use the <kbd>nCr</kbd> button.

If you want to calculate ${}_nP_r=\frac {n!}{(n-r)!}$, use the <kbd>nPr</kbd> button.

It is my strong belief that you should not be using either of these buttons until you have a clear understanding of why one of the above formulae is in fact something you want to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

In brief, combinations should be used in situations where the order doesn't matter and permutations should be used where the order does.

Say I am analysing a 49 ball lottery in which 6 balls are drawn. If I want to work out the odds of jackpot, then I need the number of different possible sets of 6 balls that can be drawn, which is 49C6. So the odds are 1/(49C6)

In contrast say I am a stage magician 'predicting' the lottery results ahead of selection, then I need to get the balls in the right order and the number of different ordered selections is 49P6, so the odds of getting this correct are 1/(49P6).

Incidentally this last number is about 0.00000001%, so if you do see a stage magician do this then you'd be justified in thinking there was something fishy about it.

Comment: @ TomHarris : Shouln't the lottery numbers be nPr .. because if the numbers are in the right order. The prize is bigger....

Comment: Depends on the specific lottery rules.

Comment: @MethodManX I was going by the UK lottery rules, I didn't know the rules were different in your country.