# Pronunciation of Combinatorial Functions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, factorial, pronunciation

A quite unimportant, but still systematically necessary question is how you go about pronouncing some of the basic combinatorial functions. Namely, the combination and permutation function. How do you *properly* pronounce $nCr$ and $nPr$?

Comment: And how is $\binom{n}{r}$ (which is the equivalent of $nCr$) pronounced ?

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r} = nCr$ is often read as "$n$ choose $r$".

Comment: I would call the corresponding buttons on a calculator the Choose and Permute buttons. I've never heard a good short name for ${}^n P_r$ for actual values of $n$ and $r$, I'd just call it "the number of permutations of $r$ objects from $n$ objects" formally, or "$r$ ordered choices of $n$ objects" informally. I've only ever really seen the number of permutations used in examples like counting words, where there's usually some concrete thing you can say instead of "objects" (like "letters" or "people").

Comment: Apparently (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022884/why-are-permutations-npr-called-variations-in-non-english-languages?rq=1), ordered choices of $r$ objects are actually called "$r$-permutations of $n$ objects".

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, the binomial coefficient $nCr = \binom{n}{r}$ is pronounced "$n$ choose $r$."

The "falling factorial" $nPr = (n)_r = r!\binom{n}{r}$ can be pronounced "$n$ to the $r$ falling.":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Alternative_notations

Comment: It is worth noting that $nPr$ can also be pronounced "$n$ permute $r$" (according to Wikipedia) which may be more natural in this case.

Comment: @C-RAM Indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_without_repetitions