# With respect to $\binom nk$, where does the extra $k!$ in the denominator of $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ come from?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

As an example, if I have 10 items and am choosing 2, the equation $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ will result in 45.

However, intuitively there are 10 items to choose from and then 9 leftover to choose from again, so the result would be 10*9=90. (Equation would be $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$)

How do I know which of these to use in what scenario?

Comment: Sure, if the order of the two elements matters, the correct answer is $90.$ But if it doesn’t?

Comment: The $k!$ comes from disregarding the "order' of the elements you choose. You can think of it in this way: the number of ordered $k$-tuples with distinct elements I can form with the set $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ ( $k \leq n$) is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, while the number of sets with $k$ elements I can form is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.

Comment: Dividing by k! removes the number of permutations of k objects chosen, when order of the objects does not matter.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429480) answer your question?

Comment: Nice find, @J.G. !